# Subversion, mark a file deleted or moved after the fact

Tags: svn

Let's say that I have two files in a Subversion repo:

```
workingcopy/
  file1.txt
  file2.txt
```

And then I rename one, external to SVN:

```
$ mv file1.txt fileA.txt
```

Now, SVN marks file1.txt as missing, `fileA.txt` as unversioned

```
$ svn st
!   file1.txt
?   fileA.txt
```

As far as SVN knows, I deleted `file1.txt` and created a completely different file `fileA.txt`, so it won't know to track changes between the files.

---

**EDIT: this does work, I just can't spell filenames correctly :)**

<strike>Similarly, if you delete a file</strike>

```
$ rm file2.txt
$ svn st
!   file2.txt
```

<strike>SVN only knows that a file went missing, and trying to mark it removed doesn't work:</strike>

```
$ svn remove file2.txt
svn: 'file2.txt' does not exist
```

---

I know that in Mercurial, you can mark a file as moved, copied, deleted, etc after the fact with the `--after` flag, regardless of what Mercurial sees in the working copy.

Is there a similar trick in SVN?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using "svn mv"?  You mention "after the fact" in the question title, but there's no such mention in the text.

Comment: Cannot repro the remove case - works for me. Does 'remove --force' solve that? FWIW I've always fixed the move case by renaming it back then svn mv-ing it back again. I had a feeling there used to be a switch on copy that just updated the metadata but that might have been in the 1.4 timeframe when they'd only just introduced it to let people patch up their old repositories.

Comment: @borrible it's an easy mistake to make - either accidentally, or in an IDE or something that's not svn-aware

Comment: @Rup - I think you misunderstood the example. I `rm` the file, then try to mark it removed with `svn remove`, as opposed to just `svn remove`. And no, `svn remove --force` does not work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - that case works for me exactly as in Rafe's answer.

Comment: @borrible - It's a side effect of (1) me not being very svn-aware, and (2) using an editor that's not svn-aware (like Rup said). I've never really thought about using the svn commands because I primarily use Mercurial where I can just specify `--after`

Comment: @Rup - Just double checked everything. The first time I tried `svn rm` I misspelled the filename, and of course to try the `--force` I just hit the up arrow and tacked it on, so it was misspelled again. Tried it with the *correct* spelling and it works fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe you need to update your version of Subversion:

```
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.6.16 (r1073529)

$ rm data.xml

$ svn status
!       data.xml

$ svn rm data.xml
D       data.xml

$ svn status
D       data.xml
```

The same thing does not work with rename, but it would be super easy to write a shell script that does it:

```
#!/bin/sh

mv $2 $1
svn rename $1 $2
```

Or just for fun you could add the following to your .bashrc or .bash_profile:

```
svn_mv_after() 
{
        mv $2 $1
        svn mv $1 $2
}

alias svnmva=svn_mv_after
```

Comment: Cool! To make it robust though you should also check for something else existing as $1 and temporarily rename that out of the way. But maybe that's going a bit far.

Comment: Turns out it was an operator error :) I just misspelled the original filename. Thanks for the handy shell function, though.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using TortiseSVN you can do this from the commit screen. Right click on the deleted and added file (the same file, just moved) together you get an option to repair the move.

http://tortoisesvn.net/repairmoves.html

Answer (score 2):

No SVN has no such thing, cause you left SVN by using an operation command "mv .." instead of "svn mv ..." for "rm ..." this is the same as well...

SVN follows filenames with the meta information "contents" whereas in git, hg and bzr the contents is follwed with the meta information file name. This is the reason why you can do things in git, hg(i don't know), bzr(i don't know as well) if you can use operation system commands for renaming and deleting files.

What you can do after you recognized that you missed something...for example if you accidently deleted a file:

```
svn revert deleted.file.ext

svn rm deleted.file.ext
```

In the case of renaming a file you can do this only in the case you didn't change anything in the new file afterwards you renamed it by

```
mv file1.txt fileA.txt
```

you can do the same

```
svn revert file1.txt
```

delete the fileA.txt first and then

```
svn mv file1.txt fileA.txt
```

If you have changed something in the renamed file (fileA.txt) just make a copy of that file and do the same procecure and replace the file contents after "svn mv ..."

Comment: For the mv fix: I think it would be easier to just `mv fileA.txt file1.txt` (i.e. put it back) then `svn mv file1.txt fileA.txt` without deleting, reverting, etc.?

Comment: _“cause you”_ : Don't blame the user for a missing feature. A lot us use IDEs and out of Subversion control renames happen all the time. Subversion is missing an important feature. End of story.

Answer (score 0):

I run Arch Linux and have the following in my `.bashrc`. It can handle a new file being in location you moved the source from and should be able to take most weird paths (e.g., starting with a dash or containing spaces). You my need to install `realpath`.

```
svma() {
    local dst src tmp

    # Check arguments
    if [[ $# != 2 ]]; then
        echo 'Usage: svma SRC DST'
        return 1
    fi

    # Ensure paths start with a slash, not a dash
    src=$(realpath -- "$1")
    dst=$(realpath -- "$2")

    # If there is a new file at the path of the source, move it to a
    # temporary name in the same directory
    if [[ -e "$src" ]]; then
        tmp=$(mktemp "--tmpdir=$(dirname "$src")" -u)
        mv "$src" "$tmp"
    fi

    # Restore the source and then have Subversion move it
    mv "$dst" "$src"
    svn mv "$src" "$dst"

    # If required, move the new file back to the source path
    if [[ -v tmp ]]; then
        mv "$tmp" "$src"
    fi
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the directory the source was in has been removed. But, I hate SVN and no longer have to deal with it and so will not be fixing that corner case. You've been warned.

Comment: Although, someone has down voted this (used to be +1). I believe it's still the most robust answer.

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted @Peter Sutton's solution a bit to handle the cases of the directory for `SRC` being missing, the directory for `DST` not being versioned yet, and taking an optional third parameter `FILE` if the source and destination filenames are the same (if `FILE` is specified, `SRC` and `DST` are directories). Again, realpath is needed, and I've only tested this in Cygwin with SVN version 1.8.11. Backup is handled using `mv -b`, which will clobber any file at `$src~`, and any unwanted directories created by mkdir will be need to be removed manually.

```
svma() {
    local dst src tmp

    # Check arguments
    if [[ ( $# != 2 ) && ( $# != 3 ) ]]; then
        echo 'Usage: svma SRC DST [FILE]'
        return 1
    fi

    # Ensure paths start with a slash, not a dash
    src=$(realpath -- "$1")
    dst=$(realpath -- "$2")

    if [[ $# == 2 ]]; then
        srcdir=$(dirname "$src")
        dstdir=$(dirname "$dst")
    else
        srcdir="$src"
        dstdir="$dst"
        src="$srcdir/$3"
        dst="$dstdir/$3"
    fi

    mkdir -p "$srcdir"
    svn add "$dstdir" --parents --depth=empty --force

    # Restore the source and then have Subversion move it
    mv -b "$dst" "$src"
    svn mv "$src" "$dst"

    # If required, move the backed-up file back to the source path
    if [[ -e "$src~" ]]; then
        mv "$src~" "$src"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing this without resorting to moving your file back:

```cpp
/* svn_mark_moved.c
 *
 * gcc svn_mark_moved.c -o svn_mark_moved $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libsvn_client libsvn_subr)
 *
 * mv file_a file_b
 * ./svn_mark_moved file_a file_b
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <svn_client.h>
#include <svn_cmdline.h>
#include <svn_pools.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const char *progname = "svn_mark_moved";

  if (argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: not enough arguments\n", progname);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (svn_cmdline_init(progname, stderr) != EXIT_SUCCESS)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

  apr_pool_t *pool = apr_allocator_owner_get(svn_pool_create_allocator(FALSE));

  svn_client_ctx_t *ctx;
  svn_error_t *err = svn_client_create_context2(&ctx, NULL, pool);
  if (err != NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", progname, err->message);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  apr_array_header_t *src_paths = apr_array_make(pool, 0, sizeof(char *));
  APR_ARRAY_PUSH(src_paths, char *) = argv[1];
  const char *dst_path = argv[2];

  err = svn_client_move7(src_paths, dst_path, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, NULL,
                         NULL, NULL, ctx, pool);

  if (err != NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", progname, err->message);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
}
```

The trick here is to pass TRUE to `metadata_only` argument of `svn_client_move7()`. I have no idea why this is not exposed by the CLI.